# JQuery is delayed of one event to retrieve DOM object using `click` event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have two questions on my webapp which are both radio input type but take the appearance and some properties of bootstrap buttons.
At each click I want to check which are the selected two button on the page.
When I click on a label, the tag `label` receives the class `.active` (from bootstrap framework I guess). I want to use it to filter which are the selected two buttons at every click of the user.

- The problem is that if I click on Option 1, at first click, the button gets active but jQuery can't retrieve the element.
- Then If I reclick on option 1 or option2, it will then properly find the element **option 1** (even if I clicked on 2).

There is a one step delay between the option I click and what jQuery find.

Here is the JS

Note: I also tried by filtering on the class `checked` of `input` tag and observe the exact same behavior

```
$(function() {
  $("label.btn").click(function() {
    console.log($("label.active").children()[0].id);
  });
})
```

And here is the pug that generate the HTML

```
.btn-group(data-toggle='buttons')
  label.btn.btn-primary
    input#option1(type='radio', name='lorem')
    |Option 1
   label.btn.btn-primary
   ...
```

NOTE :
Waiting for the answer to be edited... the solution is to replace `click` by `change`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably related to order that the event listeners are added. They will get executed in the order they are added to element.

Try adding small delay.

Example

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  var $btn = $(this)
  console.log('Has class when clicked = ', $btn.hasClass('active'));
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('Has class after small delay = ', $btn.hasClass('active'));
  },20);
}).click(function(){
   // will add class after first click handler is fired
   $(this).addClass('active')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I might use it. But I was expecting an alternative that does not involve this kind of trick :). Will validate your answer tonight.

Comment: without a lot more information I doubt you will get much else

Comment: Let's say, i wanted to use what is already implemented behind with the input/radio standard (like having only one possible selected option) but I think I am not doing the thing right

Comment: As soon as one option for each question is selected I want to do ajax request, and I want to refresh it as soon as one option is changed

Comment: As radio button looked bad, I decided to use bootstrap's one

Comment: Really not sure what you are using....a demo would help. Might be callbacks you can use in whatever plugin it is

Comment: If you are using bootstrap radios or checkbox use change event on the input

Comment: Your first solution work. I will leave it like this as it is to demonstrate and will improve it if needed. Maybe your last idea relying on event would solve this. I'll improve answer if I update my code using it.

Comment: So I just changed the event from `click` to `change` and it works perfectly fine. If you can update your answer ;)